# CQL Cassandra OR operator

Tags: select, cassandra, cql

I'm trying to do something like this in CQL:

```
SELECT address FROM Person WHERE age= 20 or age= 25
```

But Cassandra doesn't support the OR operator and I can't use IN(20, 25) either, because age isn't a primary key.  Is there any way to solve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with

SELECT address FROM Person WHERE age IN ( 20, 25 )

Comment: my understanding is Cassandra only supports IN on partition key columns: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause

Answer (score 6):

You will have to perform the disjunction client-side, or use an analytical tool like Hive or Pig.